# Better way to handle many if conditions?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

We have many different types of feeds. And one feed has many `feed_comments`. On the basis of feed type, I want to return a specific string.

```
if feed.type == 1
  if nested_comment
    str = "test"
  else if comment
    str = "test1"
  else
    str = "test2"
  end 
else if feed.type == 2
  if nested_comment
    str = "test3"
  else if comment
    str = "test4"
  else
    str = "test5"
  end 
else if feed.type == 3
  if nested_comment
    str = "test6"
  else if comment
    str = "test7"
  else
    str = "test8"
  end 
else if feed.type == 4
  if nested_comment
    str = "test9"
  else if comment
    str = "test10"
  else
    str = "test11"
  end 
end
```

What is the better way to write the code above so that I don't have to change my existing code in the future if we have many more conditions?

Comment: All the if-then-else paths has distinct outcomes (they all set `str` to different unique values), so there probably isn't a better way.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Ruby's case expression](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html) (halfway down that page)?

Comment: Hard to say because we don't know what the real intent behind the code is but I'm wondering why you have numeric `type`s rather than subclasses and why the logic isn't chopped up and delegated to those subclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code could benefit *greatly* from the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism Refactoring](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).

In general, you *never* need any conditionals at all in an object-oriented language, because object-oriented languages have runtime polymorphic message dispatch, which is more powerful than any conditional. You can *always* replace conditionals with polymorphism; Smalltalk is the existence proof of that, it doesn't even *have* conditionals in the language, they are implemented in the library using message dispatch, kind of like this:

```
class TrueClass
  def if_then_else(then_part, else_part)
    then_part.()
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def if_then_else(then_part, else_part)
    else_part.()
  end
end

(2 < 3).if_then_else(-> { puts 'True' }, -> { puts 'False' })
# True
```

Ruby *does* have conditionals, but you don't need them.

So, what does runtime polymorphic message dispatch do, exactly? Well, it basically executes different code based on the type. For example, if you say

```
foo.bar
```

different `bar` method will be ran based on the type of `foo`.

And in your case, the value you are using to base on your decision which code to execute on, is *literally* called `type`, so, you are essentially just re-implementing a basic feature of Ruby: executing different code based on the type *is* just message dispatch, which Ruby does on its own anyway.

So, in your case, you would have 4 different `Feed` classes and 2 different `Comment` classes.

Now, in your case, it is a little bit more complicated because the outcome does not depend solely on the feed type, but on the comment type as well. Ruby doesn't have multiple dispatch, so, we will either need to introduce new classes for every combination of feed type and comment type, or live with some conditionals in the final code.

So, let's start slowly improving your code. First off, I believe you mean `elsif` instead of `else if` in your code:

```
if feed.type == 1
  if nested_comment
    str = "test"
  elsif comment
    str = "test1"
  else
    str = "test2"
  end 
elsif feed.type == 2
  if nested_comment
    str = "test3"
  elsif comment
    str = "test4"
  else
    str = "test5"
  end 
elsif feed.type == 3
  if nested_comment
    str = "test6"
  elsif comment
    str = "test7"
  else
    str = "test8"
  end 
elsif feed.type == 4
  if nested_comment
    str = "test9"
  elsif comment
    str = "test10"
  else
    str = "test11"
  end 
end
```

Secondly, we can make use of the fact that conditionals in Ruby are expressions, not statements (in fact, everything in Ruby is an expression, there are no statements), and thus evaluate to a value:

```
str = if feed.type == 1
  if nested_comment
    "test"
  elsif comment
    "test1"
  else
    "test2"
  end 
elsif feed.type == 2
  if nested_comment
    "test3"
  elsif comment
    "test4"
  else
    "test5"
  end 
elsif feed.type == 3
  if nested_comment
    "test6"
  elsif comment
    "test7"
  else
    "test8"
  end 
elsif feed.type == 4
  if nested_comment
    "test9"
  elsif comment
    "test10"
  else
    "test11"
  end 
end
```

Now, we replace those `if`s with `case` expressions:

```
str = case feed.type
when 1
  case
  when nested_comment
    "test"
  when comment
    "test1"
  else
    "test2"
  end 
when 2
  case
  when nested_comment
    "test3"
  when comment
    "test4"
  else
    "test5"
  end 
when 3
  case
  when nested_comment
    "test6"
  when comment
    "test7"
  else
    "test8"
  end 
when 4
  case
  when nested_comment
    "test9"
  when comment
    "test10"
  else
    "test11"
  end 
end
```

Now, let's reformat a little, to easier see what's going on:

```
str = case feed.type
when 1
  case
  when nested_comment then "test"
  when comment        then "test1"
  else                     "test2"
  end 
when 2
  case
  when nested_comment then "test3"
  when comment        then "test4"
  else                     "test5"
  end 
when 3
  case
  when nested_comment then "test6"
  when comment        then "test7"
  else                     "test8"
  end 
when 4
  case
  when nested_comment then "test9"
  when comment        then "test10"
  else                     "test11"
  end 
end
```

It's time for our refactoring:

```
class Feed1
  def magic_string
    case
    when nested_comment then "test"
    when comment        then "test1"
    else                     "test2"
    end
  end
end

class Feed2
  def magic_string
    case
    when nested_comment then "test3"
    when comment        then "test4"
    else                     "test5"
    end
  end
end

class Feed3
  def magic_string
    case
    when nested_comment then "test6"
    when comment        then "test7"
    else                     "test8"
    end
  end
end

class Feed4
  def magic_string
    case
    when nested_comment then "test9"
    when comment        then "test10"
    else                     "test11"
    end
  end 
end

str = feed.magic_string
```

We can further reduce some duplication by introducing a method which encapsulates the comment checking (or, like I said, we can introduce comment classes).

```
class Feed
  def comment_string(nested_comment_string, comment_string, other_string)
    case
    when nested_comment then nested_comment_string
    when comment        then comment_string
    else                     other_string
    end
  end
end

class Feed1 < Feed
  def magic_string
    comment_string("test", "test1", "test2")
  end
end

class Feed2 < Feed
  def magic_string
    comment_string("test3", "test4", "test5")
  end
end

class Feed3 < Feed
  def magic_string
    comment_string("test6", "test7", "test8")
  end
end

class Feed4 < Feed
  def magic_string
    comment_string("test9", "test10", "test11")
  end 
end

str = feed.magic_string
```

Answer (score 4):

For more manageable and readable code, you could try [case statements](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#S5). Apart from this, I can't see how else you can condense the code, as each possibility has a distinct outcome like someone pointed out.

```
case feed.type
when 1
  case
  when nested_comment then str = "test"
  when comment        then str = "test2"
  else                     str = "test3"
  end
when 2
  case
  when nested_comment then str = "test"
  when comment        then str = "test2"
  else                     str = "test3"
  end
 # repeat for each feed number type
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
results = {
  1 => {
    nested_comment: 'test1',
    comment: 'test2',
    else: 'test3'
  }
}

comment_type = nested_comment ? :nested_comment : comment ? :comment : :else
results[feed.type][comment_type]
```